# Show execution time of plpgsql procedure in screen socket

Tags: linux, plpgsql, gnu-screen, psql

I need to display execution time of psql command which is executed inside screen socket.
Usually I use command:

`psql -c 'select 1' -d my_db -U my_user -h localhost`

and output of this query looks like:

`?column? - 1 row`

How can I get execution time?
I was trying with \timing, but without any results ...

Comment: `time command` shows it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define "execution time". There are many different ones here.

- Including or excluding startup time for the `psql` binary?
- Including or excluding time spent making the connection?
- Including or excluding network round trip and context switch times for sending the query and receiving the result?
- Including or excluding the time spent on the server planning the query?
- Including or excluding time spent on the server *executing* the query once it was planned?
- Including or excluding the time for formatting the result for display?

For the simplest, use the `time` command as fedorqui says. `time psql ...`.

To say how to time it, you need to first define what time you actually want.

You can then look into using `explain analyze` (possibly with separate `prepare` and `explain analyze execute`), `explain (analyze true, timing false)` to get the server runtime without detailed per-node timing overhead, the `log_min_duration_statement` server setting, `psql`'s `\timing` option, the OS `time` command, etc.

Comment: thank you. For now is enough ;) But could I ask you for some link to documentation when time command options are described and maybe something where can I check how to get different times you are writing about?

Comment: @Borys There's no one document that describes the different timing approaches. Some use operating system facilities, some facilities in `psql`, some use server features.

Comment: maybe at least options for psql time? haven't found it on postgresql.org.

Comment: @Borys Do you mean the `\timing` command? See `\?` in `psql`, or the `psql` manual.